# Server to smartphone communication

Tags: sockets, communication

I have a question regarding server to mobile device communication. I do understand how a device can connect to a server via a socket connection. Now the device disconnects again. But how can the server send some information back to this device? I mean, how is the device addressed? If there is a pool of mobile devices, the server has to somehow connect to the correct device to send the data. Can anybody tell me how this is done? How/Where does the identification of a device take place?

Comment: There are probably many possible ways this can be done. I think the most common is using "web services". The server side is basically a web server, and the mobile devices use web-based protocols to talk to the server. But there are other possibilities. Personally, I've developed a home-made TCP/IP pair of communications modules, mostly because I'm allergic to web servers. But now I have problems with firewalls, which let HTTP traffic through without batting an eyelid but think my TCP/IP traffic should be blocked at all costs. Sigh.

Comment: 'how can the server send some information back to this device?' - don't disconnect.